# error while installing Python 2.7.12 "There is a problem with this window installer package"

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I want to install Python 2.7.12 but It shows following error.

> *There is a problem with this window installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run.*

I saw one youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KikshWVWhzg) and so I provide full access to system and User. Even then, the same problem occurs.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by my own.

Actually what happens is: In past, I installed Python 2.7.10 and by mistake, I deleted python27 file from C drive. But python remains installed in computer and when I tried to uninstall it, It shows the same error as above. So to uninstall this,

first I download similar python file (python2.7.10ci) version and try to install it. And you see it got installed. Due to this a file get generated in C drive with name python27 and now I can uninstalled python which I installed a long time back.

After uninstalling old python2.7.10, I right click on python 2.7.10ci (in control panel ) and choose repair. Due to this again a file generated with python27 and now I uninstalled this too easily.

After doing all this, I downloaded python 2.7.12 and try to install. And I able to install this without any error.

Comment: Same problem, had to download the installer. But I've got 3 options, "change", "repair" or "uninstall", no installation. For me, it worked with "repair"!
Many thanks for leaving the good answer to your question!